# Adding a shell flyout item header

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.shell

In Xamarin Shell I'm trying to add a header to a flyout item. See the picture below (taken from the Xaminals project).

The 'Categories' text is a header which is not clickable or navigatable, just a static template.

I have found an article [here](https://medium.com/@thebaileybrew/xamarin-forms-shell-lets-customize-the-flyout-menu-de3df2450f56) but it's without source code and I haven't been able to construct a working example.

How can I achieve something like this?

[image]

Comment: you can get code from here https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/Xaminals/Xaminals

Comment: That is the Xaminals project but that's not what I'm looking for. I was using the Xaminals project as a base to extend it to what I want in the description above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure out a solution, so I'll put it here in case anyone wants something similar.

1. Add a FlyoutItemTemplateSelector. This class will be responsible for rendering a regular flyout item or a header template.

   ```
   public class FlyoutItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
   {
       public DataTemplate NavigationHeaderTemplate { get; set; }
       public DataTemplate NavigationItemTemplate { get; set; }

       protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
       { 
           if (item is ShellGroupItem && ((ShellGroupItem)item).Title == "Header")
           {
               // Make sure a header item is not clickable.
               ((ShellGroupItem)item).IsEnabled = false;
               return NavigationHeaderTemplate;
           }
           else
               return NavigationItemTemplate;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add the regular ItemTemplate, the new Header template and the FlyoutItemTemplateSelector control to the Shell.Resources tag in AppShell.xaml:

   ```
   <Shell.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary>
           <DataTemplate x:Key="FlyoutItemTemplate">
               <Grid>
                   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="0.25*" />
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="0.75*" />
                   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   <Label Text="{Binding Icon}"
                          FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialFontFamily}"
                          HeightRequest="45"
                          Margin="20,0,0,0"
                          FontSize="30"
                          TextColor="Black"
                          VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                   <Label Grid.Column="1"
                          Text="{Binding Title}"
                          TextColor="Black"
                          VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
               </Grid>
           </DataTemplate>
           <DataTemplate x:Key="FlyoutHeaderTemplate">
               <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                   <Label HeightRequest="35"
                          Margin="20,0,0,0"
                          Text="{Binding Title}"
                          TextColor="Black"
                          VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
               </StackLayout>
           </DataTemplate>

           <controls:FlyoutItemTemplateSelector
               x:Key="FlyoutTemplateSelector"
               NavigationHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource FlyoutHeaderTemplate}"
               NavigationItemTemplate="{StaticResource FlyoutItemTemplate}" />
       </ResourceDictionary>
   </Shell.Resources>
   ```
3. Add the Shell.ItemTemplate to the main Shell tag:

   ```
   <Shell
       ...
       Shell.ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FlyoutTemplateSelector}"
   >
   ```
4. Add the item for the header:

   ```
   <ShellContent Title="Header" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
   ```

Result:

[image]

Some notes:

- We can't remove the ContentTemplate attribute for the header item, so we must add a dummy one. I should look into that later
- Make sure the Title attribute is set to "Header". The FlyoutItemTemplateSelector control will identify this as a header template.

Like this, we can also define other templates, like a footer containing your app version, or a copyright text, etc...

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a MenuItem instead of ShellContent to achieve this. Menu item has a clicked event and command property, but if you don't bind to a command, you can effectively create a section header that does nothing when clicked. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#menu-items

```
<Shell
 ..
   <Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
      <!-- Layout for menu item to differentiate from clickable flyout items -->
    </DataTemplate>
   </Shell.MenuItemTemplate>

  <MenuItem Text="Section Header">
  <FlyoutItem .../>
  <ShellContent .../>
..
</Shell>
```